# How to require one command line action argument among several possible but exclusive?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using `argparse`, is there a simple way to specify arguments which are mutually exclusive so that the application asks for one of these arguments have to be provided but only one of them?

Example of fictive use-case:

```
> myapp.py foo --bar
"Foo(bar) - DONE"

> myapp.py read truc.txt
"Read: truc.txt - DONE"

>myapp.py foo read
Error: use "myapp.py foo [options]" or "myapp.py read [options]" (or something similar).

> myapp.py foo truc.txt
Error: "foo" action don't need additional info.

> myapp.py read --bar
Error: "read" action don't have a "--bar" option.
```

My goal is to have a "driver" application(1) that would internally apply one action depending on the first command line argument and have arguments depending on the action.

So far I see no obvious ways to do this with `argparse` without manually processing the arguments myself, but maybe I missed something Pythonic? (I'm not a Python3 expert...yet)

I call it "driver" because it might be implemented by calling another application, like gcc does with different compilers.

Comment: this looks like something you'd do with a subparser, which inherently can only support one subcommand at a time anyway?

Comment: @Eevee I am not sure I understand what is a subparser, so I don't understand your comment. Could you clarify?

Comment: it's argparse's built-in support for exactly what you're trying to replicate.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: @Eevee Thanks for the info! You should have made an answer too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is actually supported quite well in Python.

See [Mutual Exclusion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion/)

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('foo', dest='foo', nargs=1)
group.add_argument('read', dest='read', nargs=1)
args = parser.parse_args()
return args
```

Comment: How did I missed that? *palmface* Let me do some checks before validating this answer.